# Error with copying chat to a buffer

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm having some troubles copying a string from the stdin to a buffer, the string has a size of 12 characters its HS1234-0.txt for later use, here is my code:

```
while(1) {
    sem_wait(&escsem);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&esctrin);
    char filename[12];
    read(STDIN_FILENO,filename,12); //this is where I read from the stdin
    lseek(STDIN_FILENO,13,SEEK_SET);
    buffer[bufferpos]=filename; //this is where I try to copy 
    bufferpos=(bufferpos+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    conta++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&esctrin);
    sem_post(&lesem);
}
```

and here is where i try to access it, but it keeps saying that buffer[bufferpos] is null, and file_to_open is also null

```
    char* file_to_open;
    while(1){
    sem_wait(&lesem);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lertrin);
    file_to_open=buffer[bufferpos];//this is where i try to copy the string
    printf("buffer %s file %s\n",buffer[bufferpos],file_to_open);//and here it return null on both
    bufferpos=(bufferpos+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    conta++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lertrin);
    sem_post(&escsem);
    }
```

each snippet is being used from different threads and buffer declared as

```
char* buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

hope you can somehow help me guys thanks in advance

Comment: char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

Comment: `buffer[bufferpos]=filename; //this is where I try to copy` That doesn't copy anything. That just sets `buffer[bufferpos]` equal to `filename`, which is a pointer.

Comment: I thought he was aware of that since buffer is an array of type `char *`.

Comment: this line: buffer[bufferpos]=filename; will always set the buffer[bufferpos] to point to the variable 'filename'.  However the next round of input overlays what filename contains.  So the data is not saved.   And all the entries in buffer[] will point to the same variable 'filename'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `buffer` as an array of character pointers then the problem is that `filename` is a local variable only valid within that specific loop. You are saving a pointer to that local variable, but when you try to access it, it's invalid. You need to either dynamically allocate memory for the pointer, have it `static` or make it global so it's reachable from outside that scope.

If you want the "string" to be saved within the buffer instead, you need to `strlcpy`/`strncpy` the string to your buffer instead and change the type of `buffer` to `char buffer[SIZE]` to make it an array of characters, not character pointers.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* file_to_open;
while(1)
{
    // why use both a semaphore AND a mutex?
    sem_wait(&lesem);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lertrin);

    file_to_open=buffer[bufferpos];

    // per the input code, buffer[bufferpos] is a pointer to 
    // a non-null terminated array of characters (not a string due to no terminator)
    // so this will keep outputting characters until a (random) '\0'
    // char is encountered.  this is undefined behaviour
    printf("buffer %s file %s\n",buffer[bufferpos],file_to_open);

    bufferpos=(bufferpos+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    conta++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lertrin);
    sem_post(&escsem);
}
```